# SharePoint 2010 Workflow Loop Value issue

Tags: workflow, designer

I have a SharePoint list and I am writing a workflow against it.  When I add a lookup to the and email action in the body of the email, it appears fine. 
%Current Item: Pro Desc%

[image]

If I hit save and then reopen the action, the lookup changes to just [%%] and the workflow will not publish. Has Anyone Seen this before?  Any ideas?

[image]